# MySQL query: variable value for SQL does not work

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I make some functions for retrieving data.

Query results must depend on an input value.
The inputs value is in the variable `$start & $end`.

But my code returns all data not based on the input value.

It's means the variable `$start & $end` does not have value (reader null).

```
function tryme($start, $end) {

      $query = $this->db->query("
      SELECT b.liId, r.status
      FROM raws r
      LEFT JOIN books b ON r.rawsId = b.booksId
      GROUP BY b.booksId 
      HAVING 
       SUM((b.start < '$start' AND b.done < '$start') 
                   OR 
      (b.start > '$end' AND b.done > '$end')) = COUNT(*)
      ");

      return $query->result_array();
   }
```

Then I change the code with fix value, and the result is as expected.

```
   HAVING 
       SUM((b.start < '18-04-2022' AND b.done < '18-04-2022') 
                   OR 
      (b.start > '19-04-2022' AND b.done > '19-04-2022')) = COUNT(*)
      ");
```

So what was the mistake, how to use the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables `$start` and `$end` are not being expanded in your query string.  Assign your query string to variable and print it out to confirm.  That said, use [bind](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings) variables instead of interpolating strings:

```
      $query = $this->db->query("
          SELECT b.liId, r.status
          FROM raws r
          LEFT JOIN books b ON r.rawsId = b.booksId
          GROUP BY b.booksId 
          HAVING SUM((b.start < ? AND b.done < ?) OR
              (b.start > ? AND b.done > ?)) = COUNT(*)
      ", [$start, $start, $end, $end]);
```

Comment: I have followed the documentation and your code advice for correct syntax but faced errors in the SQL syntax `for the right syntax to use near '? AND b.done < ?) OR (b.start > ? A...' at line 14`.  But if use single quote at the **?** like this  `((b.start < '?' AND b.done < '?') OR (b.start > '?' AND b.done > '?')` will be no error, but again the variable still not readed.

Comment: it's have been solved, add associative array `(b.start < ? AND b.done < ?) OR
              (b.start > ? AND b.done > ?)) = COUNT(*)
      ", [$start, $start, $end, $end]);`